# Coderush code clean up settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush

When I run Coderush's clean up file command it takes code formated like this:

```
public object GetConfig() 
{
    //fluent mappings are lined up 
    return MsConfig.MsSql2008
           .ShowSql()
           .UseReflectionOptimizer()
           .ConnectionString(_connstring);
}
```

and formats it like this:

```
public object GetConfig() 
{
    //fluent mappings are left justified  
    return MsConfig.MsSql2008
    .ShowSql()
    .UseReflectionOptimizer()
    .ConnectionString(_connstring);
}
```

How do I prevent coderush from left justifying my method chainings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this behavior is by-design and you can't prevent this, unfortunately. We (DevExpress) have a suggestion registered for keeping user indents. We are going to implement it in a future release (probably, in the 2012.1 release).

Comment: has this been implemented? I downloaded the trial today and I don't see it and I want the indents I provided particularly with Linq lambdas.